# module 'pynput.keyboard' has no attribute 'press'

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard, pynput

I'm using python 3.8 and pynput 1.7.2

This is my code.

```
import pynput
import time
time.sleep(5)
pynput.keyboard.press("a")
```

This is the error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File ".\test.py", line 4, in <module>
        pynput.keyboard.press("a")
AttributeError: module 'pynput.keyboard' has no attribute 'press'
```

I've tried doing this*

```
from pynput import keyboard, controller
```

* I also tried controller with a capital C

It says controller is not a package of pynput.

Also for some reason when I use release instead of press it doesn't throw any errors,
It also doesn't give errors when I use press or release for pynput.mouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [documentation](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html) for the syntax to use.

Controller is a package within `pynput.keyboard`.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Controller

keyboard = Controller()
keyboard.press('a')
```

Comment: I feel like such a fool now, I completely looked over ```from pynput.keyboard import Controller```